# Ng-repeat submit form with generated fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-ng-form

I have this issue, where i have a ng-repeat where i add some input fields and i want to submit the value of these inputs to the generated form - dosn't work with ng-model, but can i get by input name inside the form tag.

```
<li ng-repeat="group in tournament.groups">
    <form novalidate ng-submit="tournament.submit(group.team1, group.team2)">
        <span>
            {{ group.team1.name }}
            <input type="number" name="team1" placeholder="x">
        </span> - <span>
            <input type="number" name="team2" placeholder="x">
            {{ group.team2.name }}
        </span>

        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the input using `ng-model` & `name` attribute of `form` is missing which because of which your `ng-submit` is not getting fire.

When you add name attribute to your `form` suppose `name="team"` at that time angular does create a new variable inside scope & add all the form related information about the validity of form & the information of each field.

**Markup**

```
<li ng-repeat="group in tournament.groups">
    <form name="team" novalidate ng-submit="tournament.submit(group.team1, group.team2)">
        <span>
            {{ group.team1.name }}
            <input type="number" name="team1" placeholder="x" ng-model="group.team1"/>
        </span> - <span>
            <input type="number" name="team2" placeholder="x" ng-model="group.team2"/>
            {{ group.team2.name }}
        </span>

        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
</li>
```

Comment: This dosn't work because if i have 6 sets of team1 & team2 they will have the same value?

Comment: @SimonPertersen No.. `ng-repeat` will create new form with name `team` of each element..So values will be different for each `li`..By the way `ng-model` should be more specific like `ng-model="group.team1"` & `ng-model="group.team2"`

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-model:

**View:**

```
<li ng-repeat="group in tournament.groups">
    <form novalidate ng-submit="submit()">
        <span>
            {{ group.team1.name }}
            <input type="number" name="team1" placeholder="x" ng-model="group.team1.name">
        </span> - <span>
            <input type="number" name="team2" placeholder="x" ng-model="group.team2.name">
            {{ group.team2.name }}
        </span>

        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
</li>
```

**in controller:**

```
$scope.submit = function(){
   console.log($scope.group.team1.name);
   console.log($scope.group.team2.name);
};
```

You will get your value. Try once my code.

Answer (score 0):

In the approach you have used you will be having multiple forms. I would suggest you to have only one form and iterate inside the form as follows :

```
<form name="team" novalidate ng-submit="tournament.submit(group.team1, group.team2)">
    <li ng-repeat="group in tournament.groups">

        <span>
            {{ group.team1.name }}
            <input type="number" name="team1" placeholder="x" ng-model="team1"/>
        </span> - <span>
            <input type="number" name="team2" placeholder="x" ng-model="team2"/>
            {{ group.team2.name }}
        </span>

        <button type="submit">Save</button>
   </li>
</form>
```

And have the ng-model updated for each and every group accordingly using '$index' (as ng-model="team{{$index}}")

I guess this should do the trick.

Comment: there is no need to maintain separate array from `team` that will mess if you use any filtering on the records.

Comment: IMHO it is also not the best way to have multiple forms created in the DOM.

Comment: who said that..? Do you have any reference link who state that it is BAD way..? It totally depend on the requirement of project.. Then what would be the best way to render multiple forms?