# How to submit data from input fields generated using ng-repeat and get the value of all the input fields?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angular js and I need to create a form where the input fields will be dynamically generated based on a loop and I need to send all the field's data to an API.

This is the string  that I get from the backend

```
"Earth:planet,life,solar,global$#@data_col.signal:gateway ox,gw ox,gateway all ox,all sig,,gw signal gain,gateway"
```

This is my part of the html below where I process the string

```
<div class="container-fluid synBox">
        <span><b>Enter synonyms:</b></span>
        <form enctype='application/json'>
            <div class="form-group" name="syn" ng-repeat="n in message.expert_advice.split('$#@')">
                 <span class="fonts" style="color:#487baa;"><b>{{n.split(":")[0]}}</b></span>
                 <input class="form-control" id="expert_advice_input" type="text" ng-model={{n.split(":")[1]}}  placeholder="" name={{n.split(":")[0]}} value={{n.split(":")[1]}}>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block" ng-click="submit_synonyms()">Submit</button>
        </form>
 </div>
```

Here is my js for the function in onclick `submit_synonyms()`

```
$scope.submit_synonyms = function() {
  var variable = document.getElementById('expert_advice_input').value;
  console.log(variable)
}
```

Here is what it looks like in the UI

[image]

I was hoping that I would get the value for all input fields but when I click the button I only get the value of the first input field (as seen in the console).

```
planet,life,solar,global
```

I also followed other similar questions in stackoverflow like [Ng-repeat submit form with generated fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089140/ng-repeat-submit-form-with-generated-fields) but couldn't figure out how to apply it in my situtation. What am I doing wrong?

**Do note that the number of input fields can be dynamic based on the string supplied to me.**

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

Just for the sake of clarity, the reason I am doing the splits on the string is to get the heading and the remaining comma separated strings in the input fields to which a user can add more string and hit the submit button.

Comment: First store the split values in an array say 'sets'. This will help you to identify the length of elements. Then, assign unique ids by concatenating key/index such as expert_advice_input{index}. when submitting the button, based on the length of the sets you can iterate and fetch the values.

Comment: @Ananthaprakash hey could you provide an example code. That would help me to understand

Answer (score 0):

write the following in your controller

```
const param = <input> //"Earth:planet,life,solar,global$#@data_col.signal:gateway ox,gw ox,gateway all ox,all sig,,gw signal gain,gateway";
  $scope.param = param.split('$#@').reduce((acc,val)=> {
    const spl = val.split(':');
    acc[spl[0]] = spl[1];
    return acc;
  },{});
```

and following in your template or html

```
<ul >
     <li data-ng-repeat="(key,value) in param"><label for={{key}}>{{key}}</label><input type='text' value='{{value}}'</li>
  </ul>
```

add styles and optimize code style.